# Pattern based, batch file rename in terminal

Tags: rename, regex, batch-rename

I need to rename the following:

```
file_001_loremipsum.png
file_002_dolor.png
file_003_sit.png
file_004_amet.png
file_105_randomness.png
```

into

```
upl_loremipsum.png
upl_dolor.png
upl_sit.png
upl_amet.png
upl_randomness.png
```

How do I make it happen with just one simple line of terminal command?

Comment: A failsafe regex-based python version which works recursively on all subfolders: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698169/191246

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The solution to the above example, using [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename):

```
rename -v -n 's/file_\d{1,3}/upl/' file_*.png
```

Usage:

```
rename [options] [Perl regex search/replace expression] [files]
```

From `man rename`:

```
   -v, --verbose
           Verbose: print names of files successfully renamed.
   -n, --no-act
           No Action: show what files would have been renamed.
```

rename MAY take regex as the arguments.

What we are looking at is the content between the single quotes `'`. You can place regex separated by `/`.

Formula: `s/(1)/(2)/` where `(1)` = search pattern, and `(2)` = replace pattern.

So, [familiarize youself with regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and enjoy pattern based batch file renaming!

Comment: I know this is Ubuntu, but if anyone ends up here even though they were looking for an OS X solution (I did), `rename` is easily installed with `brew install rename`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.10, the `--no-act` flag is `--nono` instead. This answer could also be a bit more explicit: `[files]` refers to an initial pattern matching files in the current directory that one wants to potentially rename (e.g., `*` matches everything, but only in the current directory).

Comment: Your link points to another `rename`, which has format `rename from to file` and does not support regular expressions. Actually, my Linux distribution (Cent OS 7) has exactly that version.

Comment: For my sys no-action is "--nono" : `rename --verbose --nono 's/ /_/' *` => show final names of files after space would be replaced with underscore in current directory, for all files (`*`)

Comment: apparently, my `rename from util-linux 2.37.2` on Ubuntu 21.04 does not support this

Answer (score 9):

This can be done with little magic of bash parameter expansion!

```
for f in file_[0-9]*_*; do mv $f upl_${f#file_[0-9]*_}; done
```

`file_[0-9]*_*;` - First pattern is used to go trough all files that begin with 'file_anynumber_'
`${f#file_[0-9]*_}` - The second pattern `file_[0-9]*_` is used in parameter expansion which tells bash to remove 'file_anynumber_' from the begging of the string.

For more information on `Parameter expansion`:

```
man bash
```

Comment: Note that this uses globs, not regex, so `[0-9]*` will match one digit followed by any string. There's probably a better way to match just numbers, but I can't think of anything succinct.

Comment: Would you also be able to suggest a way to have this command work recursively in all subdirectories?

Answer (score 7):

if files are in severals directories, use rename after a find like :

```
find -iname file_*.png -type f -exec rename -n 's/file_[0-9]{3}(.*\.png)/upl$1/' {} \;
```

the -n after rename is to test, remove it to proceed !-)

like this, you associate find and rename power.

Personally, I used it to rename sources header .h to .hpp

```
find -iname *.h -type f -exec rename 's/(.*\.)h/$1hpp/' {} \;
```

Comment: There's documentation for the `-iname`, `-type`, and `-exec` flags at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/find.1.html#expression. (`find --help` isn't particularly helpful for this command.) TL;DR: `-iname` matches a pattern case‐insensitively; `-type f` matches “regular files”; and `-exec` executes an expression until it encounters a `;` (semicolon) character.