# Batch Rename Using Regex but Mainaining Some Substring

Tags: rename, regex, batch-rename

I made a lot of research before I put this question. I found a different links to do batch rename using regex like this and other similars:

*[Pattern based, batch file rename in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283145/pattern-based-batch-file-rename-in-terminal)

My problem is this, I want to do batch rename using Regex but my code doesn't work.

I have inside a folder different files named like this:

```
name_house_1_door.jpg
name_house_2_door.jpg
name_house_3_door.jpg
name_house_4_door.jpg
```

And I want to rename the files like this:

```
name_house_1.jpg
name_house_2.jpg
name_house_3.jpg
name_house_4.jpg
```

The code that approximate most of that I want was:

```
$  rename -v 's/house\_[0-9]\_door/house_[0-9]/'
```

But as you should know the first file was renamed as: name_house_[0-9].jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Rename Files in Folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/561814/batch-rename-files-in-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [backreferences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences). Character classes don't mean anything in the replacement expression. In fact, few characters have special meanings in the replacement expression.
I suppose something like:

```
rename -v 's/house_([0-9])_door/house_$1/'
```

(or)

```
rename -v 's/(house_[0-9])_door/$1/'
```

Also, do use the `-n` flag to see what renamings will happen before actually performing them.

Answer (score 3):

A much easier way would be to just delete `_door` using rename:

```
rename -v 's/_door//' *
```

This searches for `_door` and replaces it with nothing, essentially deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are escaping the underscore in the search side of the expression and should not be.
2. You need a sub-search (the numbers) and a place holder to store and use the result of the sub-search.

Adding parentheses around the [0-9] will create the needed sub-search. Since it is the first sub-search it can be referred to as $1 in the replace side.
The result follows..

```
rename -v 's/house_([0-9])\_door/house_$1/' *
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But you are also "escaping the underscore in the search side". This contradiction may confuse researchers.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Fish Shell

```
for file in *.jpg;  
    mv -n $file (basename $file _door.jpg).jpg; 
end
```