# Batch Rename Files in Folder

Tags: rename, batch-rename

How can I strip out some text from filenames in a folder?

I'm currently attempting:

```
rename s/"NEWER_(.*?)"//g *
```

But nothing it getting renamed

I have a parent folder, with a bunch of sub-folders, within are files, that OneDrive thought would be a great idea to append a " (NEWER_timestamp)" to, and I'd like to remove that.

Example File Names:

```
getyou.ico (NEWER_1417529079.87)
o7pm.ico (NEWER_1417529184.89)
o7th.ico (NEWER_1417529135.81)
```

Comment: Can you post an example filename?

Comment: sure.  updated question with some

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```bsh
find /path/to/parrent-dir -type f -exec rename -n 's:[^/]*(.*) .*$:$1:' {} +

./o7th.ico (NEWER_1417529135.81)                                 renamed as /o7th.ico
./sub-dir (NEWER_1417529135.81)/getyou.ico (NEWER_1417529079.87) renamed as /sub-dir (NEWER_1417529135.81)/getyou.ico
./sub-dir (NEWER_1417529135.81)/o7pm.ico (NEWER_1417529184.89)   renamed as /sub-dir (NEWER_1417529135.81)/o7pm.ico
./getyou.ico (NEWER_1417529079.87)                               renamed as /getyou.ico
./o7pm.ico (NEWER_1417529184.89)                                 renamed as /o7pm.ico
```

- All `[^/]*(.*) .*$` matches only the last part of the path that doesn't contain a `/`. And
- In above regex, `(.*)` is a group of matching everything after last `/` and before a space. Its back-reference will be `$1`.
- `.*$` matches everything to end`$` of files name after space.
- Finally in replacement part of rename `s/.../REPLACEMENT/`, we just kept the matched group that is between last `\` and a space`(.*)` which is known as group of matches.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the quotes outside the regex (within, they are taken literally as quotes), and escape `(`. Try;

```
rename -n 's/ \(NEWER_\d{10}.\d{2}\)$//' *NEWER*
```

The precision of the expression might not be necessary, but you can't be too cautious when modifying files.

Comment: all this is doing is hanging with `reading filenames from STDIN` I am already inside the Parent folder where all these files are

Comment: @Kevin "If no filenames are given on the command line, filenames will be read via standard input." And since the shell leaves `*NEWER*` as it is if no expansions are found, you must have made a mistake, or are using a shell which replaced an unmatched wildcard with nothing.

Comment: copied and pasted, into Ubuntu 14.10 shell