# Renaming multiple files at once, with the same extension

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I'm currently in a situation, where I need to rename a bunch of files, inside different folders, with the same extension (SRT).

Currently, my directory "setup" is like this:

```
This is a folder (2000)
   - This.is.a.folder.2000
     - This.is.a.folder.2000.wmv
     - This.is.a.folder.2000.txt
     - This.is.a.folder.2000.srt

This is also a folder (2001)
   - This.is.also.a.folder.2001
     - This.is.also.a.folder.2001.wmv
     - This.is.also.a.folder.2001.txt
     - This.is.also.a.folder.2001.srt
```

And I need to rename the SRT files to be like so:

```
This is a folder (2000)
   - This.is.a.folder.2000
     - This.is.a.folder.2000.wmv
     - This.is.a.folder.2000.txt
     - This.is.a.folder.2000.en.srt

This is also a folder (2001)
   - This.is.also.a.folder.2001
     - This.is.also.a.folder.2001.wmv
     - This.is.also.a.folder.2001.txt
     - This.is.also.a.folder.2001.en.srt
```

Is there any way to go about this? I'm running an Ubuntu server, with only a terminal available.

If anyone can help me with this, I would be very grateful :).

Comment: See the duplicate. Of course, you need to adapt the options you provide to the rename command for your specific case ('s/\.srt/\.en\.srt/')

Comment: So like? `rename 's/\.srt/\.en\.srt/' */*/*`

Comment: See my written out answer, where I develop on the duplicate question for your specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561814/batch-rename-files-in-folder?rq=1) for the overall approach. You obviously need to adapt to your specific requirements:

- For the parameters of `rename`, you can provide `'s/\.srt/\.en\.srt/'`, which will search `.srt` and change by `.en.srt`.
- To work more safely (and probably faster), restrict find to locating only your `.srt`. files. To that aim, add the `-name '*.srt'` option to the find command.
- Test-run first by adding the `-n` option to the rename command. This shows how the renames will be done without actually performing them. If all looks fine, re-run the command without the `-n` option.

The command, based on the post which also asked a similar question, will look like

```
find /path/to/parrent-dir -type f -name '*.srt' -exec rename -n 's/\.srt/.en.srt/' {} +
```

Comment: Running `find . -type f -name '*.srt' -exec rename -n 's/\.srt/\.en\.srt' "{}" \;` gives me this error: `Substitution replacement not terminated at (user-supplied code).`

Comment: @PerlDuck For sure you are right. I have corrected this.

Comment: `rename` can rename multiple files, so use `-exec rename ... {} +` -- the `+` form passes multiple files at a time.

Comment: @glennjackman yes, but then you are building very long command lines. Allegedly, limits are high, but using \; there is no limit in the number of files that can be processed. I indicated this already in my answer, so the user is informed and can choose.

Comment: You can simplify this a bit I think - the `.` only needs to be escaped on the `pattern` side of a `s/pattern/replacement/`. In the general case you should probably anchor `\.srt$` since `rename` will attempt to replace the first occurrence (even if it is in a directory name for example).

Comment: see my answer for a simplified version, you’re welcome to copy it if you want to

Comment: @PerlDuck, I like to quote the braces: not to protect the filename, but to protect the braces themselves from shell brace-expansions. I do know that the shell does not expand empty braces. I like to say to the shell "find wants these braces; don't you touch them".

Comment: @PerlDuck I missed your comment the first time round. Although "issues" may have be a great word here, optimization never harms.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `bash`’s `globstar` option, enabled with `shopt -s globstar`:

> If set, the pattern `**` used in a pathname expansion context will match  all  files  and  zero or more directories and subdirectories.

```
printf '%s\0' **/*.srt | xargs -0 rename 's/srt$/en.$&/'
```

This builds a zero-delimited list of every file matching `*.srt` in or under the current directory and pipes it to `xargs` which runs `rename` as often as necessary. The `rename` expression substitutes the final “srt” with “en.” followed by the matched string (`$&`).

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── test.srt
├── 2
│   └── 3
│       └── test.srt
├── srt.srt
└── test.srt
$ shopt -s globstar
$ printf '%s\0' **/*.srt | xargs -0 rename 's/srt$/en.$&/'
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── test.en.srt
├── 2
│   └── 3
│       └── test.en.srt
├── srt.en.srt
└── test.en.srt
```

Answer (score 2):

If your system doesn't have `rename` (or has the wrong `rename`<sup>1</sup>), then you can do this particular kind of replacement easily with shell parameter expansion `${f%.srt}` to remove the trailing `.srt` from `$f`:

```
find path/to/dir -name '*.srt' -execdir sh -c '
  for f; do echo mv "$f" "${f%.srt}.en.srt"; done
' sh {} +
```

Remove the `echo` once you are happy that it's doing the right thing.

1. [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)

Comment: It’s a matter of taste, but there’s a substitution function in parameter expansion as well, and it supports anchoring: `"${f/%srt/en.srt}"`

Comment: @dessert in ksh/bash/zsh but not in plain sh I think?

Comment: You’re right – I’m susceptible to basisms. ;)

Comment: @dessert - yeah I had to check to be sure